# List keeps going on forever on the x axis

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a make-shift code to show multiple pages in one html. I have it to where you can only have one page shown and you can switch between four pages. But, whenever I try to have more rows of li, it goes past the screen. How can I fix this. Basically, instead of going to the next row, it just keeps adding them horizontally.

cases.html

```
<div class="main_div">
                <div class="inner_div">
                    <a name="product"></a>
                    <ul id="Div1">
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li><br/>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="Div2" style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="Div3" style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="Div4" style="display: none;">
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h2>Yeet</h2>
                            <img src="images/test.png">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Page 1</a> | 
                    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Page 2</a> | 
                    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Page 3</a> | 
                    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div4');">Page 4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

style.css

```
.main_div{
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
.inner_div{
    width: 900px;
}
.inner_div ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.inner_div ul li{
    width: 290px;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.inner_div ul img{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px 45px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.buttons{
    text-align: center;
}
```

pages.js

```
var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
var visibleDivId = null;
function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}
function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to:

```
.inner_div ul { ... }
```

this:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

It is because flex default behaviour is to get in one line the children;